# ng-show, only show but don't hide element if click again

Tags: angularjs

```js
var app=angular.module('app',[]);
```

```css
.box
{
width:50px;
height:50px;
background-color:red;
}
span
{
position:absolute;
left:190px;
top:10px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.23/angular.min.js"></script>
<div ng-app="app">
  <input ng-click="showBox =! showBox" placeholder="Click me"/>
  <div class="box" ng-show="showBox"></div>
  <span>Hide box</span>
</div>
```

Hey, I have one question for very new AngularJS users. This is only exapmle but shows idea. When click in input red div will show,but if you click again div hide. But I don't want that second click hide this div, I would like that click in `Hide box` hide div. I would like that click in input only show red div but don't hide if click again

Answer (score 1, accepted):

use

```
ng-click="showBox = true"
```

assuming it's initialized as false.

If you want to hide using the Hide Box use

```
<span ng-click="showBox = false">Hide box</span>
```

Answer (score 1):

just set it to true,

```
ng-click="showBox = true"
```

**DEMO**

```js
var app=angular.module('app',[]);
app.controller("dobController", ["$scope",
  function($scope) {
  $scope.showBox =false;
  }
]);
```

```css
.box
{
width:50px;
height:50px;
background-color:red;
}
span
{
position:absolute;
left:190px;
top:10px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.23/angular.min.js"></script>
<div ng-app="app">
  <input ng-click="showBox = true" placeholder="Click me"/>
  <div class="box" ng-show="showBox"></div>
  <span>Hide box</span>
</div>
```